# Run the same Procedure at the same time in Oracle?

Tags: oracle, plsql, plsqldeveloper

I'm currently using:

```
BEGIN
PACKAGE1.PROCEDURE1('PARAM_1','PARAM_A','PARAM_B');
END;
```

I need to run the same procedure multiple times (Oracle), but this time changing only the first parameter, for example:

```
PACKAGE1.PROCEDURE1('PARAM_2','PARAM_A','PARAM_B');
PACKAGE1.PROCEDURE1('PARAM_3','PARAM_A','PARAM_B');
```

How can i accomplish this? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Put three calls in the anonymous block?  Or, if the first parameter values are coming from somewhere in the database, write a loop that calls the procedure.

Comment: Could you make a brief example, please?

Comment: Of which approach?  An example requires understanding the requirements but I don't yet.  Are the values of the first parameter coming from somewhere in the database so that you can loop over them?  Your title says "at the same time"-- do you really intend to run these in parallel?  Are they built so that they can be monitored by whatever thread spawned them?  Or do you really mean that you want to make one request to the database and run the procedure a number of times serially?

Comment: I think his problem is changing parameter name. if yes Look at my answear about execute_immidiate statement could be helpfull.

Comment: No the problem is running them all at the same time, I think.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In anonym plsql block write a loop with number of iteration depends on how many parameters You want to call procedure with. At the top of loop put logic that will be setting a paramter an then call a procedure with it. But remember that there is no option in plsql to read data from console or user during a program run.
// I think that You can ask about passing an other variable in loop each time, I am not sure is it can be done in plsql You can try use

> execute_immidiate

command with string conncatenate as a parameter name.

Answer (score 0):

You Package Procedure must be with IN OUT parameter and i assume the first parameter is IN so the master should take care of the thing of supplying the values to this.

Procedure is working as expected now the external stream of incoming this have to take which is coming from outer source or some other passing mechanism.

Just align those to this package procedure and you may call this procedure as many time as you want according to IN this takes.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to submit it as job if you want to run the same procedure simultaneously.

```
BEGIN

begin
    dbms_scheduler.create_job 
    (  
      job_name      =>  'One_Time_Job_1',  
      job_type      =>  'PLSQL_BLOCK',  
      job_action    =>  'begin PACKAGE1.PROCEDURE1('PARAM_2','PARAM_A','PARAM_B'); end;',  
      start_date    =>  sysdate,  
      enabled       =>  TRUE,  
      auto_drop     =>  TRUE,  
      comments      =>  'one-time job');
  end;


begin
    dbms_scheduler.create_job 
    (  
      job_name      =>  'One_Time_Job_2',  
      job_type      =>  'PLSQL_BLOCK',  
      job_action    =>  'begin PACKAGE1.PROCEDURE1('PARAM_3','PARAM_A','PARAM_B'); end;',  
      start_date    =>  sysdate,  
      enabled       =>  TRUE,  
      auto_drop     =>  TRUE,  
      comments      =>  'one-time job');
  end;

END;
```

look at [DBMS_SCHEDULER](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28419/d_sched.htm) for further details.

Answer (score 0):

If this is for an ongoing production process with a fixed number of parallel procedures, I would consider using a Scheduler Chain.

This would execute all the procedures at the same time, and give you extra features, such as:

1. the ability to run other procedures when one or all of them has completed
2. control over which procedures run afterwards, depending on the success or failure of the procedures.